# C++: about subsequent operations of overloaded operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


void testfn(double* v1, double *v2, double *v3, int n);//I must use this function

class CLS{
private:
    vector<double> v;
public:
    CLS(vector<double> vin);
    CLS operator+(CLS & A);
    CLS operator*(CLS & A);
};

CLS::CLS(vector<double> vin)
{
    v=vin;
}

CLS CLS::operator*(CLS &A){
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    vector<double> vtmp(v.size(),0);
    testfn(&*A.v.begin(),&*v.begin(),&*vtmp.begin(),(int)A.v.size());
    CLS C(vtmp);
    return C;
}

CLS CLS::operator+(CLS &A){
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    vector<double> vtmp(v.size(),0);
    testfn(&*A.v.begin(),&*v.begin(),&*vtmp.begin(),(int)A.v.size());
    CLS C(vtmp);
    return C;
}

void testfn(double* v1, double *v2, double *v3, int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        *v3=*v1+*v2;
        ++v1;
        ++v2;
        ++v3;
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<double> v1(100,1.0), v2(100,2.0), v3(100,0.0);
    CLS C1(v1),C2(v2),C3(v3);
    CLS C4=C1*(C1+(C2*C3+C2))*C1*C2*C3+C1+C2+C3;
    return 0;
}
```

I create class CLS and defined two operators + and *. I want to use these operators as simply as how we use + and * for integers and doubles. Therefore I have a test line in the main  `CLS C4=C1*(C1+(C2*C3+C2))*C1*C2*C3+C1+C2+C3;`. However I get tons of errors when compiling this code using gcc. I am not familiar enough with the rules of operator overloading. How should I modify the definition (maybe just parameters?) of * and + so that `CLS C4=C1*(C1+(C2*C3+C2))*C1*C2*C3+C1+C2+C3;` is valid?

Supplements: I don't know how to use const parameter for operator+ and * , since the definition of these two operators involve another function `testfn`, whose parameters are double* instead of const double*. Further more, I do not want to change any part in the definition of `testfn` because in my real code it corresponds to a function in LAPACK which I absolutely have no right to change.

Comment: " I am not familiar enough with the rules of operator overloading." And is it so hard to google for 'c++ operator plus overload'?

Comment: On the line of "teach a man to fish" [here's the reference for 'binary operation overload'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators). Feel free to read the whole page (for all operators).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I have added some explanation in the original post about why I can not use const parameters for + and *. It is totally possible that those difficulties can be got around with. But I do not know how.

Comment: If you know for sure that `testfn` will not modify `*v1` or `*v2` then you can safely cast away the `const` on those arguments when calling `testfn`.

Comment: @Resorter C++11 you say? Maybe is time for you to lean about [`move copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [`move assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) rather than rely on compiler generated ones? See also [the rule of 5/3/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Relevance: you return objects by value, should understand what are the mechanisms underneath,

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thanks for letting me know and I would like to learn. But are you sure it solves my problem? I really want to solve this problem first.

Comment: @Resorter Of course I'm sure. "Have a fish" in my answer and don't forget to practice fishing.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to define `operator+` and `operator*` as a friend function, so that if there are implicit conversions from some other type to `CLS`, then the operator can be used. If it's a member function, then if the first operand is not an `CLS`, it wouldn't be found.

```
friend CLS operator+(CLS lhs, const CLS& rhs) 
{
  // Do your logic here
  return lhs; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I will keep it in mind. It indeed helps me to organize the code in a better way.

Comment: Hi Nikita, now I want to extend the definition of matrix multiplication to vector * matrix, matrix * vector, vector * vector (inner product), and vector * vector (outer product). How should I declare the function so that it works in all five cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use spaces in your code, it's horrible to read. Don't use uppercase letters for both typenames and variables, that's also horrible to read.

This isn't essential, but a small optimisation, pass the constructor argument by reference, and then initialize the `v` member in the constructor init list (not by assigning to it in the body):

```
CLS::CLS(const vector<double>& vin) : v(vin)
{
}
```

I would add a new constructor, that takes the desired size, and sizes the `v` member to that immediately, a it makes the code below simpler:

```
CLS::CLS(int n) : v(n, 0)
{
}
```

First add `const` to the function parameter and the member function itself:

```
CLS CLS::operator*(const CLS& a) const {
                   ^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

Then default construct an empty `C` object for the result, with a vector member of the desired size:

```
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    CLS result(v.size());
```

If you create copies of the data vector and work on those copies then you can make the member function and its argument const:

```
    vector<double> v1 = a.v;
    vector<double> v2 = v;
```

Now you can get non-const pointers to the data in those vectors, and you can write the output straight into `C.v` instead of writing into `vtmp` and then copying that into the returned object:

```
    testfn(&*v1.begin(), &*v2.begin(), &*result.v.begin(), v.size());
```

Finally return the result:

```
    return result;
}
```

And exactly the same changes for the other function:

```
CLS CLS::operator+(const CLS& a) const {
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    CLS result(v.size());
    vector<double> v1 = a.v;
    vector<double> v2 = v;
    testfn(&*v1.begin(), &*v2.begin(), &*result.v.begin(), v.size());
    return result;
}
```

Now this will be able to accept const arguments, so should work with the temporary objects that are created by each `C1+C2` or `C3*C4` expression.

The code is slightly less efficient, because of the extra copies of the data, but the optimisation in the constructor helps that. Even those inefficiencies can be solved if you're able to use C++11, but takes more work.

Firstly, C++11 provides `vector<T>::data()` to get a pointer, which is much clearer than `&*v.begin()`. (It's not part of the C++ standard before C++11, but GCC provides it even for C++98). You can change the code shown above to use `v.data()` instead of `&*v.begin()`, as shown below.

In C++11 you can add additional overloads that work on temporary objects, by binding (non-const) *rvalue references* to the temporaries. Because the rvalue references give you non-const access to the temporary objects you don't need to make copies of  their data to get non-const pointers, and can use them directly. Add these operator overloads in addition to the original ones shown above:

```
CLS CLS::operator+(CLS&& a) && {
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    CLS result(v.size());
    testfn(a.v.data(), v.data(), result.v.data(), v.size());
    return result;
}

CLS CLS::operator*(CLS&& a) && {
    //assuming the two vectors have the same length
    CLS result(v.size());
    testfn(a.v.data(), v.data(), result.v.data(), v.size());
    return result;
}
```

This avoids making any copies inside the intermediate temporary objects created by your arithmetic expressions. I also find it *much* simpler to understand and easier to read.

A complete working example is at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e40d20eb7f1e9fc

Comment: Your optimization suggestion makes absolutely sense. Making copies of CLS is known but, as you said, it is less efficient. I am indeed using C++11, so can you tell me how to completely solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I have corrected your typo when you define result. But why does it still not compile on my own computer? I declare + as CLS operator+(CLS&& a) &&; under public. Then I just copied your code and corrected the typo but it still did not compile.

Comment: I fixed some more typos, and added a link to a complete working example. Make sure you add the new overloaded operators to the class definition, and add `const` to the original declarations in the class definition.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry but can you avoid copying the whole CLS in + and *?

Comment: CLS CLS::operator+(CLS&& a) &&  does not seem to work on my computer.

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" mean? The copies are necessary to get non-const data, because of the dumb API for `testfn`. If you're positive it doesn't need non-const pointers you could use casts, but that seems unwise to me.

Answer (score 1):

The unusual requirement to use the `testfn` with all params non-const is a bit weirds, but it's... umm.. <strike>reluctantly acceptable</strike> inacceptable for the case of complex expressions - the first two params of the testfn need to be `const double*`.

**Rationale:** C++ standard requires temporaries to be bound to `const references` - some [interesting details here](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

@Resorter says:

> "Thanks for letting me know and I would like to learn. But are you sure **it** solves my problem? I really want to solve this problem first."

[where **it** is 'move constructor' and 'move assignment']

---

The following "fish" assumes you have read/learnt fishing [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [move assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) and the [rules of 5/3/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three),

Supplementary study material: [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) - when the compiler is allowed to skip the copy/move constructors even when they would have side effects.

```
// some implementations
void testfn0(const double* v1, const double *v2, double *v3, int n) {
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    v3[i]=v1[i]+v2[i];
  }
}

void testfn1(double* v1, double *v2, double *v3, int n) {
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    v3[i]=v1[i]*v2[i];
  }
}

class CLS {
  std::vector<double> v;
public:
  // constructor taking a const reference
  CLS(const std::vector<double>& in) : v(in) {
    std::cout << "copy vec" << std::endl;
  }

  // extra constructor with rvalue reference: it will "canibalize" the parameter
  CLS(std::vector<double>&& in) : v(in) {
    std::cout << "move vec" << std::endl;
  }

  // Rule of 5 applied
  // Copy constructor
  CLS(const CLS& other) : v(other.v) {
    std::cout << "copy CLS" << std::endl;
  }
  // Move constructor
  CLS(CLS&& other) : v(std::move(other.v)) {
    std::cout << "move CLS" << std::endl;
  }
  ~CLS() { }

  // Copy assgn
  CLS& operator=(const CLS& o) {
    this->v=o.v;
    std::cout << "assgn CLS" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
  // Move assgn
  CLS& operator=(CLS&& other) {
    this->v=std::move(other.v);
    std::cout << "move CLS" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  // WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT const FOR COMPLEX EXPRESSIONS
  //                       |
  //              ----------
  //              V
  CLS operator+(const CLS& rhs) {
    std::vector<double> vtmp(v.size(),0);
    testfn0(&*rhs.v.begin(),&*v.begin(),&*vtmp.begin(),(int)rhs.v.size());

    CLS ret(std::move(vtmp));
    return ret;
  }

  // WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT const FOR COMPLEX EXPRESSIONS
  //                       |
  //              ----------
  //              V
  CLS operator*(const CLS& rhs) {
    std::vector<double> vtmp(v.size(),0);
    testfn1(&*rhs.v.begin(),&*v.begin(),&*vtmp.begin(),(int)rhs.v.size());

    CLS ret(std::move(vtmp));
    return ret;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "\n--- inits " << std::endl;
  CLS a(std::vector<double>{1,2,3}); // move vec
  CLS b(std::vector<double>{3,2,1}); // move vec

  std::cout << "\n--- add " << std::endl;
  CLS c=a+b; // move vec and 'silence' (copy elision)
  std::cout << "\n--- mul " << std::endl;
  CLS d=a*b; // move vec and 'silence' (copy elision)

  std::cout << "\n--- copy " << std::endl;
  CLS m=c; // Copy CLS - constructor

  std::cout << "\n--- move " << std::endl;
  CLS n=std::move(d); // Move CLS - constructor

  std::cout << "\n--- assgn (d=c) and copy (x=c)" << std::endl;
  CLS x=d=c;
}
```

Comment: @Resorter Ah, (just in case) don't forget to compile with `-std=c++11` or better

Comment: Boss, your code has no problem. I can compile and run it. But I want + and * to be used in a way like x=a+b*c+d. I added this line then I failed compiling again.

Comment: @Resorter you are right. Are you sure the `testfn` must have the all-no-const signature instead of  `void testfn(const double* v1, const double *v2, double *v3, int n)`? Why can't the first 2 params be `const`? What exactly that function is (those functions are) supposed to do?

Comment: I gotta use this (and some others) LAPACK function in my real code

Comment: extern "C"
{
    void DGEMM ( char *TRANSA, char *TRANSB, int *M, int *N, int *K, double *ALPHA, double *A, int
                *LDA, double *B, int *LDB, double *BETA, double *C, int *LDC);

Comment: extern "C"
{
    void DGEMM ( char *TRANSA, char *TRANSB, int *M, int *N, int *K, double *ALPHA, double *A, int
                *LDA, double *B, int *LDB, double *BETA, double *C, int *LDC);}

Comment: @Resorter At the very least **can that `fntest` function work well if `v1`==`v3` and/or `v2`=='v3`**?

Comment: (It posts when I hit enter and just wanted to change a line. ) I am not sure if I can change this declaration in my code.

Comment: In DGEMM, A, B and C corresponds to v1, v2, and v3.

Comment: @Resorter Mate, I assume that at least those matrices you are trying to add, multiply are square and have the same dimension. Confirm/comment/deny? (if you confirm, there may be a solution to your problem. Othrwise, only the addition can be rerouted through LAPACK).

Comment: Nope. They can be nXm matrices.

Comment: It is not a good idea to write the matrix multiplication by myself. I tried and it is too slow.

Comment: @Resorter. "They can be nXm matrices" Then you cannot do the multiplication: by keeping only a sd:vector, you are losing the numRows/numCols info.

Comment: The class I show in this post of course can not do it. But I have all necessary information in my real code. My goal is that I want to overload those operators so that I can do matrix operations like MATLAB. But the problem, which I stated in this post, is that there are some restrictions on the parameter of the class function which make the goal not so easy to achieve.

Comment: In this post I am just trying to implement vector sum and vector dot product. But you have seen the problem. The question is how to solve it.

Comment: @Resorter Ok, I see. Looking over the [DGEMM specification/source](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigtIzF9erPAhUP6GMKHZPkA5sQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netlib.org%2Fclapack%2Fcblas%2Fdgemm.c&usg=AFQjCNFlQEApdr1Ukf7cLrHDTz7KaugF1w&sig2=AIp2q7O_DtALiZBIw3xIfw&bvm=bv.136593572,bs.2,d.cGc), the A and B are unchanged on exit. So a cast from a `const double*` to `double*` are safe (therefore your `testfn` can have take the `testfn(const double* v1, const double *v2, double *v3, int n)` form and perform the cast inside)

Comment: Then take a look at DGESVD. U, V, and S are changed.

Comment: @Resorter stay tuned, I'm looking for a solution ( :) maybe you'll end by offering me a contract or at least some SO rep points :) )

Comment: Sure.  I truly appreciate your spending time on this and discussing with me.  I was tuned. Maybe my English is not good enough.

Comment: @Resorter OK, as a learning ground this may be a good field. But are you sure you want to reinvent a wheel [invented so many times before](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/353)? For DGEMM the solution is not that hard, but for the SUV it won't be trivial. Have a look over the linked and let me know if you really want to go ahead with your approach (SO has an [`Eigen` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eigen) and I'm seeing quite a big activity - seems to be a [popular software](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) )

Comment: I thought this had been aware of by experts. So it should just had been a problem of asking and answer. C++ has been developed for so many years I don't believe it does not have enough function to live well with LAPACK.

Comment: @Resorter Seeing that many implementations of Matrix and related linear algebra, it looks like the modern languages prefer to be safe/bug adverse (as for commercial products) than fast (as Fortran was). This would explain why "expert awareness" doesn't boil down into a simple answer - looks like there are many tradeoffs to be done and different "experts" chose different trade-offs.  On another line, there is a [LAPack++](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug_old/node18.html) library out-there - quite old.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for these introductions. How do I give you rep? I just voted you up but I can only do it for once.

Comment: I think you are right about DGEMM. I don't know why I was worried about DGESVD.

Comment: @Resorter "How do I give you rep? I just voted you up but I can only do it for once." You just did, thanks. As the answer doesn't cover your initial Q in full, it is not fair to accept it (accepting shows when you hover under the "vote down arrow" and a green checkmark is meant to appear: pressing on it accepts the answer)

Comment: It looks like const_cast can save this issue.

Comment: @Resorter I added the explanation why it doesn't work without `const double*`. Thanks for accepting before reaching the state of a complete answer.

Comment: Nope I think const_cast completely solves my problem.

Comment: @Resorter `const_cast` to non-consts solves the issue, but it comes with the attached responsibility for the coder to make sure it doesn't screw what really needs to remain constant.

Comment: Why did you need && (in addition to &) in your definition of + and * ?

Comment: And you probably want const_cast otherwise it can not be compiled on my computer.

Comment: @Resorter will help exactly in complex expression, some compilers may use them instead of copy elision. In any case, I hope you see the usefulness of the constructor using `std::vector&&`, right?

Comment: @Resorter Sorry, I forgot adjusting the fntest1's first 2 params to `const double*`. True, the const_cast will need to be used, but do it as close as possible to the LAPACK layer: that is, inside the equiv of fntest.

Comment: Then why did you dump the definition of + and * using && in your current version of code...

Comment: How much is the computational cost and other kinds of cost if I use const_cast on a large matrix?

Comment: @Resorter Zero cost - resolved at compilation time. If the compiler allows the cast, it is not different to a C-style cast, See [`static_cast` ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) The allowed casting are: same type different const/volatile, enums to/from integrals, derived class pointer to base class pointer, `void*` to any pointer type.

Comment: Do I really need to define the move/copy constructor/assignment by myself in this example? I see on a book that these are defined by compiler by default. And it seems that the default copy/move constructor/assignment do not cause problems.

Comment: @Resorter "I see on a book that these are defined by compiler by default." It is safer to do so - even when you explicitly declare them as "default". Look at the [Rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) (and the other rules above) and [some concerns about it](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/a-concern-about-rule-of-zero.html) - the comments on the (last linked) blog entry certainly worth reading too.

Comment: In your last link (some concerns about it), Scott suggests that define all five special functions. Because his concern is that, when adding a self-defined destructor for debugging, the implicit move constructor/assignment will be replaced by copy constructor/assignment. But someone else said below his blog that this is no longer the case. What is the situation now? Do I still need to define the move/copy assignment/constructor?

Comment: @Resorter If you plan to consume your library for yourself in strict controlled conditions, you can test your compiler's-of-choice support in this respect and act accordingly (e.g. implement a class storing a huge std::vector, deal with some complex expressions that would normally result in calling move constructor and examine the execution time/memory consumption over "has" and "has not" a declared destructor). If you plan to use the lib on no matter what compiler/OS context, I guess it's not much to explicitly declare default constructors/assign ops.

Comment: @Resorter Is only 1.5 years since the blog entry, I won't know how much adhesion the nowadays compilers have to the standard, but I can tell you gcc4.x is still distributed as default by Ubuntu 14.04 and that version of compiler is in maintenance mode (bug fixes rather than enhancements; I'm using gcc 5.4 for this reason, even if I had to use a different repo to get 5.4 instead of the default 4.9). Others may be too lazy to use a different repo (and worried enough by systemd to stay with 14.04 for as long as possible).

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing  your opinion.